# Code is compiled and run successfully but expected output is to print "Sub" is not getting printed. What is the error in this code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, delegates, multicastdelegate

What is the problem in this code?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
public delegate void del();

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        del d = new del(add);
        d += sub;
    }

    public static void add()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("add");
    }

    public static void sub()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sub");
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Youre never invoking the delegate

Comment: expected output is `add` and  `Sub`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke your delegate:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        del d = new del(add);
        d += sub;

        d.Invoke();
    }

    public static void add()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("add");
    }

    public static void sub()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sub");
    }
  } 
}
```